# Anime with the main character that can transform his arm into a giant cannon

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was a kid, about 8 to 11 years old, I saw this anime about a teenage boy that can transform his arm into a giant cannon. There's this antagonist that eats a whole human from that anime and he also stole their abilities after eating them. The antagonist can also transform his arm into a cannon but much bigger than the main character.

Comment: When were you a kid? It would help to pin down a time period.

Comment: could it maybe be `MegaMan`?

Comment: Does any... *bullet* point in the "Anime & Manga" folder of https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArmCannon ring a bell to you? (beware, TvTropes will ruin your life!)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Possibly Trigun? Bit of a stretch perhaps.

Comment: Not only when were you a kid (give a _year_), do you remember where you saw it? On tv, rented from a store? Do you remember what language you saw it in?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think its mid 2008

Comment: @Derek I dont think its megaman .

Comment: @n_b I saw it on Animax . I think its a english subbed anime

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202026/anime-episode-with-duel-fight-sequence-where-villain-blows-light-and-heavy-bubbl (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

The anime you are thinking about is [The Law of Ueki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Law_of_Ueki).

The Giant Cannon is "KUROGANE" (Sorry it's still so cool to say it), his Sacred Treasure.

[image: Giant Cannon]

His power is basically to turn Garbage into Trees. You might remember his Cannon being Tree-ish from the bottom.

The antagonist (Hanon), eats humans and keeps them inside his body and absorbs their powers.

[image: Hanon]

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit like Trigun, which was aired in the US on Cartoon Network in the early 2000's on Adult Swim. I don't remember the specific age of the protagonist, but he portrayed himself very childishly to keep other people off guard. In the final(?) episode, he fights with his brother, and they can both turn their arms into organic guns.

And, as luck may have it, Funimation (who own the distribution rights in the US) has put the entire series (in Japanese) up on youtube! Here's a clip of the protagonist (in red) getting his arm turned into a gun:

Answer (score -1):

I thought it was Space Cobra. Maybe Trigun

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain why you think this might be it.

Comment: In addition to what TLC said, you might want to split that into two answers - one for Space Cobra and one for Trigun. This way people can vote on them separately, and only the right one (if it's one of these two) gets accepted.