# Anime episode with duel/fight sequence where villain blows light and heavy bubbles, mentor interferes, goes to hell and takes villain with him

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd watched an episode a while ago, but don't know which anime it is from.

Details:

- I'd reckon I watched it at least 5 years ago, so a lot of the details in this sub-section are hazy.
- The episode I watched was in English, though I can't remember whether the dubbing was of low or high quality.
- I watched it on TV, very likely on Animax.
- I think it was Japanese-style, Shonen
- Definitely in the fantasy genre. Duelling/battle-oriented, with characters possessing magical powers/abilities

Story:

The antagonist could blow light and heavy bubbles, and was extremely powerful. The protagonist gets caught in a light bubble, floats up really high, and a heavy bubble then hits it, causing him to come crashing down. His mentor interferes and catches him. His mentor then gets sent to hell for interfering in a duel. The mentor rises back up from hell, grabs onto the antagonist, and takes him to hell with him
(I think he might have said something along the lines of "I'm taking you with me").

Other details:

- The antagonist, protagonist and mentor were all male. There was possibly one more character, likely female, watching the events unfold.
- I think the antagonoist traps trees (or logs) in bubbles and uses them against the protagonist-- it is possible that these logs (or perhaps they were wooden, log-like spikes?) had something to do with the protagonist's powers, though I don't remember his powers
- The mentor was relatively old, the protagonist young.
- Whent the mentor gets sent to hell, a ring of red light surrounds him. Someone also explicitly says that he interfered in the duel, knowing full well that the penalty was getting sent to hell, though I can't remember who.

Comment: [Bubbles, you say?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AihUU1DO8tM)

Comment: My first thought is Naruto, where soap bubble ninjutsu is a thing. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Soap_Bubble_Ninjutsu can't think of an episode like the one you describe though, hence why I haven't added this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Law of Ueki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Law_of_Ueki) where Ueki fights with [Robert](http://lou.wikia.com/wiki/Robert_Haydn) I dont remember the exact episode but it ticks all the boxes.

1. People have one (sometimes two) magical powers and need to duel (the patron of the winner becomes the next god).
2. Their masters (or patrons) cannot interfere in their duels (if they do they get dragged to hell but are still considered as candidates for god)
3. Robert (The main antagonist who is also a heavenly being) has powers related to gravity which manifests as bubbles [his initial ability is 'perfection' which buffs his '[sacred weapons](http://lou.wikia.com/wiki/Sacred_Weapons)' and his evolved ability is being gravity manipulation]
4. It was on animax
5. The protagonist Ueki has the ability to make trash into trees
6. It was a forced battle where Ueki's teammates were held hostage for the fight and had to watch (one of them is female and two [or three] are male)
7. His teacher (who is not his patron) interferes and gets dragged to hell

Comment: That's the antagonist: http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Robert_Haydn !
Thank you, I've been searching for this for years :D

Comment: Looks like I was referring to ep 6, "Law of Goodbye". Plot (from Wikipedia): Mr. K forbids Ueki from challenging Robert Haydn, telling him that he is just too strong for Ueki. When Ueki hears that Robert has viciously attacked B.J., though, he just gets angry and becomes determined to challenge him. The two meet and Mr. K's words were correct. Robert is able to deflect every attack Ueki sends at him with his bubbles. Ueki is about to pay the ultimate price for his foolishness, but luckily Mr. K steps in with a last second rescue. But aren’t God Candidates forbidden from helping their chosen?